# An Algorithm for software that simulates an "economy"

Tags: algorithm

I'm writing some software that simulates an 'economy' in a game.

I say 'economy' because this is used very loosely; it's pretty off from an economy you probably picture.

Currently, items have a few variables attached to them: price, floor, ceiling, velocity, spread, and stock.

Price and floor are the max and min prices the price can reach, velocity is the change in price per transaction, stock is self-explanatory, and spread is a variable I used for some calculation but is no longer useful.

My previous idea was to change the price by the amount of items purchased * velocity. So if I bought 10 cars for $10, and the velocity was $5, it would increase by (10 cars * $5) = $50, for a new price of $60. This was a simple way to demonstrate a higher "demand". Likewise selling a car would DECREASE the price by amount * velocity.

This is flawed in the sense that a player can buy 10 cars for $10 ($100 total), and then the price becomes $60 and they can sell them back immediately for $600.

Stock is an optional factor, so try not to utilize that.

My question is: how would you create this 'dynamic economy', and if you could, utilize the floor, ceiling, price, and velocity in your algorithm.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? How to calculate how much a purchace of X items should cost, and what is the price after it?

Comment: Flagged. Belongs in math or game development.

Comment: Sounds like you need a textbook on economic (econometric?) modelling.